# segmented controller for annotations

Tags: ios, annotations, nsmutablearray, mapkit

I need to show like 20 annotations around the city center of Amsterdam. 
I want the annotations be separated in 3 kinds of subject. I want to control these subject annotations with a Segmented controller. 
Example: in segment 1 I need to show 'x' annotations. in segment 2 I need to show 'x' (other) annotations. same with segment 3. Each time I press one of the segments I want to remove the others and show the ones I clicked.

This is what I got so far:

ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Annotations.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create the region
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = 52.369331;
center.longitude = 4.893467;

//Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.04f;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.04f;

myRegion.center = center;
myRegion.span = span;

[myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

//Annotation
NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotations *myAnn;

myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.369331;
location.longitude = 4.893467;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Nes";
myAnn.subtitle = @"Nes";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.379680;
location.longitude = 4.886858;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Noordermarkt";
myAnn.subtitle = @"Noordermarkt";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
location.latitude = 52.371532;
location.longitude = 4.898080;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"De Wallen";
myAnn.subtitle = @"De Wallen";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

[self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations]; 
} 

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {

switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex ) {
    case 0:
    //for example:
    //Show here the annotation of Nes
    break;
case 1:
    //for example:
    //Show here the annotation of Noordermarkt
    break;
case 2:
    //for example:
    //Show here the annotation of De Wallen
    break;

default:
    break;

}
} 
@end
```

Annotations.H:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotations : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

Update 2:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locationArrays;
@property int currentAnnotation;

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Annotations.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = 52.369331;
    center.longitude = 4.893467;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.04f;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.04f;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    [myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

    //Annotation
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Annotations *myAnn;

    NSMutableArray *category1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *category2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *category3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *locationArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.369331;
    location.longitude = 4.893467;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Nes";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Nes";
    [category1 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 1' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category1];

    myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.379680;
    location.longitude = 4.886858;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Noordermarkt";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Noordermarkt";
    [category2 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 2' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category2];

    myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.371532;
    location.longitude = 4.898080;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"De Wallen";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"De Wallen";
    [category3 addObject:myAnn];

    myAnn = [[Annotations alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.368585;
    location.longitude = 4.886457;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Bijbels Museum";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Bijbels Museum";
    [category3 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 3' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category3];

    self.currentAnnotation = 0;

    [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[locationArrays objectAtIndex:0]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [self setMyMapView:nil];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    int newAnnotations=((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (newAnnotations != self.currentAnnotation)
    {
        [self.myMapView removeAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:self.currentAnnotation]];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:newAnnotations]];
        self.currentAnnotation = newAnnotations;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is, how to add these three annotations to my Segmented Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses 3 arrays to hold the categories of annotations and selects the appropriate one based on the segmented controller

```
ViewController.h 

@interface PWViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;
@property int currentAnnotation;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locationArrays;

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;


ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    self.locationArrays=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = 52.369331;
    center.longitude = 4.893467;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.04f;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.04f;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    [self.myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

    //Annotation
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Annotation *myAnn;

    NSMutableArray *category1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *category2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *category3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.369331;
    location.longitude = 4.893467;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Nes";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Nes";
    [category1 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 1' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category1];

    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.379680;
    location.longitude = 4.886858;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Noordermarkt";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Noordermarkt";
    [category2 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 2' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category2];

    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.371532;
    location.longitude = 4.898080;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"De Wallen";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"De Wallen";
    [category3 addObject:myAnn];

    myAnn = [[Annotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = 52.368585;
    location.longitude = 4.886457;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Bijbels Museum";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"Bijbels Museum";
    [category3 addObject:myAnn];
    //TODO create and add other 'category 3' locations in the same way
    [self.locationArrays addObject:category3];

    self.currentAnnotation = 0;

    [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:0]];
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    int newAnnotations=((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (newAnnotations != self.currentAnnotation)
    {
        [self.myMapView removeAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:self.currentAnnotation]];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:newAnnotations]];
        self.currentAnnotation = newAnnotations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the way of using 3 arrays of animations and then using another outer Array. Still a beginner at this.

Comment: Create 4 NSMutableArrays - category1, category2, category3 and locationArrays. Add your category1 annotations to category1,my our category2 annotations to category2 array and the same with category3. Now add category1, category2 and category3 to locationArrays with addObject the same as you are currently doing then use the code from my answer

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it's still not working.
For adding the categories ann. to the category arrays I did [locations addObject:category1]; Then I is put the CategoriesArray in the locationsArrays like this: [locationArrays addObject:category1];

Comment: Try [locations addObject:category1] and then [locationArrays addObject:locations] so the objects in your locationArrays are arrays that contain your annotations - this is assuming that category1 is one of your annotations

Comment: Already tried that. Don't know what the problem seems to be. Maybe something with the way I made Array Annotations: locations?

Comment: It's doesn't recognise the 'currentAnnotation' property and the locationsArray which in the UISegmentedControl.

Comment: Still getting error with the:
 - self.locationArrays= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 - [self.locationArrays addObject:category1]; and 2 & 3.
 - self.currentAnnotations=0;
 - [self.myMapView addAnnotations:[locationArrays objectAtIndex:0]];
  And still can't find the property currentAnnotation and locationsArray in the UISegmentedControl.

Did a clean project, but same errors

Comment: What error are you getting with self.locationArrays?  Did you declare it as `@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *locationArrays;` in your .h file?  Same with with currentAnnotations - `@property int currentAnnotation;`

Comment: Wauw, think that was the problem... But I now get a application crash ;(

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: You should make sure your arrays are set up in `viewDidLoad` or a method that you call from `viewDidLoad` - Sounds like you are accessing the array before it has been initialised

Comment: Strange, only got the IBAction outside the viewDidLoad.

Comment: The IBAction will be called as a result of the user interacting with your `UISegmentedControl`.  viewDidLoad is called when you view is loaded (but before it is displayed).  You need to make sure that your properties are set up in viewDidLoad so that when the user triggers the IBAction you don't get the error with an empty array.  You can also set a breakpoint in the IBAction method and inspect your variables to make sure they are set correctly

Comment: Can't find the problem. Set a breakpoint at every line where an Array in involved. Also I can't see what is happening in 'IBAction', when using breakpoints.. When debugging, all the object went trough the exact Array, but it seems like 'category3' is the only object that placed in the 'locationsArray'. I'll update the code.

Comment: The last line in your viewDidLoad is incorrect - it should be `[self.myMapView addAnnotations:[self.locationArrays objectAtIndex:0]];` note the self.locationArrays . To prevent any confusion remove the definition for `NSMutableArray *locationArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` at the start of viewDidLoad.  If your IBAction breakpoint isn't triggering then it means that the method isn't being called.  Is the little bullet beside the method definition in Xcode filled in?  which event from the segmented control have you bound to the IBAction?

Comment: Yeah problem solved. Also the bullet is filled with the 'main.storyboard - Plain Segmented Control'. In the 'Connections Inspector' I've connect the 'View Controller setmap:' to 'value changed' and myMapView to the View Controller. But still don't get the annotations at the map.

Comment: OK.  I just built a quick version of your app and then updated my answer with my working code.

Comment: Nice man, changed some code and it works! What was the last issue? 
Thanks for keeping in touch!

Comment: I think it was still a mix up between the self.locationArrays and the locationArrays somewhere in the code.  Once I got rid of the unused local variables and made sure there were no other references to them it was all good.